# Javascript add class to element using js

Tags: javascript

i have created a list with js(works fine) whenever the user is focusing the password field:

```
let password = document.querySelectorAll(".control-group")[3];
password.addEventListener("focusin", () => {
  let row = document.createElement("ul");
  row.innerHTML = `
    <li>One lowercase character</li>
    <li>One uppercase character</li>
    <li>One number</li>
    <li>One soecial character</li>
    <li>One lowercase character</li>
    <li>Eight characters minimum</li>
  `;
  password.appendChild(row);
});
```

Then i have created and added a hidden class to the ul when the field loses focus but the ul class doesn't disappears when the password field loses focus. Any idea?

```
password.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
  let style = document.createElement("style");
  style.type = "text/css";
  let row = document.createElement("ul");
  style.innerHTML = `.hidden {display: none}`;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
  row.classList.add("hidden");
});
```

Comment: You never append `row` to the DOM in the `focusout` event listener. What is it for?

Comment: Did you mean for that to be the row that was added in the `focusin` listener?

Comment: Adding and removing elements and styles dynamically like this is poor design. You should create the HTML statically, and then just add/remove classes to hide and show it.

Comment: because is suposed to be append by the focus in

Comment: i have to do it using js

Comment: you don't append row in the focusout

Comment: `this.parentElement.appendChild(row)` in your `focusout`

Comment: Also, please be aware that you would be creating a new style element everytime you focusout

Comment: And every time you focus in, you create another `ul` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this works for you:

```js
let password = document.querySelectorAll(".control-group")[0];
password.addEventListener("focusin", () => {
  let row = document.createElement("ul");
  row.innerHTML = `
    <li>One lowercase character</li>
    <li>One uppercase character</li>
    <li>One number</li>
    <li>One soecial character</li>
    <li>One lowercase character</li>
    <li>Eight characters minimum</li>
  `;
  password.appendChild(row);
});


password.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
  let rows = document.querySelectorAll("ul");
  rows.forEach(row => {
    row.style = 'display: none'
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <input type="text" name="password" />
</div>
```

**Note:** As per the question it was understood that you intentionally wanted to create new `<ul>`'s. But if the idea was just to show and hide the `<ul>` then the following would be a **improved version of my answer**.

```js
let password = document.querySelectorAll(".control-group")[0];

password.addEventListener("focusin", () => {
  let row = document.querySelector("ul");
  row.classList.toggle('hidden');
});


password.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
  let row = document.querySelector("ul");
  row.classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <input type="text" name="password" />
  <ul class="hidden">
    <li>One lowercase character</li>
    <li>One uppercase character</li>
    <li>One number</li>
    <li>One soecial character</li>
    <li>One lowercase character</li>
    <li>Eight characters minimum</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: While this does visually solve the issue it never removes the lists from the DOM so every time that focus enters and then leaves the password field you will have a new hidden list.

I would recommend adding the list to the html with a default style of `display: none` and then switch it to `display:block` on `focusin` and back to `display:none` on focus out.

Comment: As per the question he wanted to create new `<ul>` and append to the div each time. But if you wish to improve on the idea then, @Eljano I would suggest you to directly have the <ul> defined in the HTML and then change the display to `block` or `none` in code.

Comment: @Naylor thanks for pointing out. I have updated my answer now so that it may help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding the class to the row that was appended by the `focusin` listener. You're creating a new `ul`, but never appending it to the DOM.

Use `querySelector()` to get the `ul` that's already a child of the `password` element.

```js
password.addEventListener("focusout", () => {

  let row = password.querySelector("ul");
  if (row) {
    let style = document.createElement("style");
    style.type = "text/css";
    style.innerHTML = `.hidden {display: none}`;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
    row.classList.add("hidden");
  }
});
```

Your code adds another `<ul>` every time you focus in, and another `<style>` every time you focus out. You should fix it to only create them the first time each listener runs.

Comment: wouldn't that create a new style tag everytime focusout event is fired?

Comment: Yes, it will. This is a terrible design.

Answer (score 0):

The `ul` element doesn't disappear, because you didn't give it the relevant class.

Using CSS class is good, but if you still have to *create* the CSS class through JavaScript, then it is really overkill. Just use the `style` property.

Secondly, create the list *once*, not every time the password input gets focus.

For example:

```js
let password = document.querySelector(".control-group");

let ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.style.display = "none"; // <-- hide by default;
for (let item of ["One lowercase character", "One uppercase character",
                 "One number", "One special character", 
                 "One lowercase character", "Eight characters minimum"]) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = item;
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
password.appendChild(ul);

password.addEventListener("focusin",  () => ul.style.display = ""    );
password.addEventListener("focusout", () => ul.style.display = "none");
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <input type="text" name="password" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class or id to the `<ul>` element so you can target it after.

And because you're creating a new element and then hiding it, every time you return your focus to the element it will create a new `<ul>`. Maybe remove it from the DOM could be a way to go.

```
let password = document.querySelectorAll(".control-group")[3];
password.addEventListener("focusin", () => {
  let row = document.createElement("ul");
  row.classList.add("custom-class");
  row.innerHTML = `
    <li>One lowercase character</li>
    <li>One uppercase character</li>
    <li>One number</li>
    <li>One soecial character</li>
    <li>One lowercase character</li>
    <li>Eight characters minimum</li>
  `;
  password.appendChild(row);
});

password.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
  let row = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-class")[0]; //if you go for an id, it may be nicer
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
});
```

Let me know if it work for you.